# Android Open cursors when running applyBatch() method

Tags: android

I have an activity that inserts a big number of contacts on an Android device by executing applyBatch() commands on the ContentResolver. I run this application on many Android devices and it seems to work ok except Galaxy S2 I9100 phone (with Android 4.0 version) where after a number of inserts, I get the following exception for each command that is executed thereafter:

```
E/CursorWindow( 5727): Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db' of size 2097152 due to error -12.
E/JavaBinder( 5727): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
E/JavaBinder( 5727): android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=819 (# cursors opened by pid 5701=819)
E/JavaBinder( 5727):    at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:104)
E/JavaBinder( 5727):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow
(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
E/JavaBinder( 5727):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:162)
E/JavaBinder( 5727):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:156)
E/JavaBinder( 5727):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:161)
E/JavaBinder( 5727):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:209)
E/JavaBinder( 5727):    at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.findGroupByRawContactId(ContactsProvider2.java:3738)
E/JavaBinder( 5727):    at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.addAutoAddMembership(ContactsProvider2.java:3725)
E/JavaBinder( 5727):    at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.insertRawContact(ContactsProvider2.java:3713)
E/JavaBinder( 5727):    at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.insertInTransaction(ContactsProvider2.java:3360)
E/JavaBinder( 5727):    at com.android.providers.contacts.AbstractContactsProvider.insert(AbstractContactsProvider.java:108)
E/JavaBinder( 5727):    at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.insert(ContactsProvider2.java:2605)
E/JavaBinder( 5727):    at android.content.ContentProviderOperation.apply(ContentProviderOperation.java:214)
E/JavaBinder( 5727):    at com.android.providers.contacts.AbstractContactsProvider.applyBatch(AbstractContactsProvider.java:203)
E/JavaBinder( 5727):    at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.applyBatch(ContactsProvider2.java:2755)
E/JavaBinder( 5727):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.applyBatch(ContentProvider.java:208)
E/JavaBinder( 5727):    at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:179)
E/JavaBinder( 5727):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
E/JavaBinder( 5727):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

The PID mentioned in the exception is running the  **android.process.acore** package.

Indeed when I monitor the process while the initial inserts are being perfrormed, I see that this PID is generating logs that mention that "cursors are finalized prior to closing"

Does anyone have a clue about this strange behaviour?

Below is the code that performs the inserts:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "")
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "").build());

        ops.addAll(vCardUtility.readVCard(vCard));

        Log.w(TAG, "TRYING TO EXECUTE " + ops.size() + " OPERATIONS");
        r = cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

Where readVcard just creates a list of ContentProviderOperation objects to insert the contact details.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same problem on Samsun S3.

Answer (score 1):

Close the cursor to avoid that error.

Example:

```
yourCursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just saw this crash, and it seems to be related to too many open `Cursor`s, seems like we weren't closing cursors and that build up and reached some open-cursors limit.

See this line from the `logcat`:

```
android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: 
Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. 
# Open Cursors=351 
(# cursors opened by pid 3862=1) 
(# cursors opened by pid 12138=347) 
(# cursors opened by pid 15078=1) 
(# cursors opened by pid 19150=1) 
(# cursors opened by pid 21804=1)
```